# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group.addLocations returns true but no locations added

Tags: python, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

Trying to copy a private image to another datacenter using Python.  Code below returns true but transaction is not initiated and image is not copied.

```
info=client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group'].addLocations({'id':449494},id=123456)
```

id is confirmed valid - using id with other services (getBlockDevices,getStatus,getChildren) provides appropriate responses.

what is wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 0):

You should send between **[ ]** the template for locations, please thy the following

```
info=client['SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group'].addLocations([{'id':449494}],id=123456)
```

References:

- [SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group::addLocations](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/addLocations)